# BackgroundSubtractor getBackgroundImage() function return empty Image

Tags: java, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.0 in Java, I want to use `BackgroundSubtractor` to get foreground objects and also I want to get the background image, but when I call `getBackgroundImage()`  method of `BackgroundSubtractor` return me an empty image. The code is bellow:

```
Mat backgroundImage = new Mat();
mog2.getBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
```

According to the OpenCV Documentation this method can return the background image and put the data to the given Mat:

*Computes a background image.
C++: void BackgroundSubtractor::getBackgroundImage(OutputArray backgroundImage) const
Parameters: 
backgroundImage – The output background image.*

What will be the problem? If anyone knows about this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!